# Pay using paypal api

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have the following function that excepts 4 fields. I need to post these values to Paypal and complete the transaction

```
string PostToPayPalMethod (string card_n,string pass, string cvc, string amount) {

// Now i need to post these value to paypal

    return "success";


}
```

The user will be entering his/her card details (`card_n`,`pass`,`cvc`) through our web interface, and i will pass it to the `PostToPayPalMethod` to complete the transaction.

I was looking at the classic API, but it was directing the customer to it login to paypal first to complete a transaction.

Can someone point me to complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the new REST api provided by PayPal - documentation available here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

You can make credit card payments using the API, though I believe you need to collect a couple of more pieces of information.

Comment: So will i be able to ask an individual to type in the card number/expiry and pass those values to Paypal to complete the transaction ? It doesn't say so in the API. help

Comment: Yes - you can pass the credit card information in funding_instruments element [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment)